# How to load images in UIScrollView asynchronously?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage

HI,

I am getting my images using `JSON` and I need to display image at a time when my app is running so please tell me how to use asynchronous method to load the images into the `UIScrollView`?

Thanks.

Comment: @user732177: I know a Good sample project for doing that in the `UITableView` I thought you might get the idea but for the `UIScrollView`, Here you go [Asynchronous Loading of Images in UIScrollview](https://github.com/akosma/async-uitableview/) and Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

whether you use a UITableView or a UIScrollView, you will use the same pattern, its just that you have a bit more plumbing to do with the UIScrollView.   I would say use the UITableView unless you want to roll your own multi-column image thumbnail picker.

With the UIScrollView, you will need to create your own virtual rows and columns and detect when the ScrollView has scrolled a new row or a new column into view. You will need to queue (remove) the images that have scrolled out of view, and then load the images that have come into view.  All in all, this is not trivial code.

The UITableView does all this for you (rows only, no concept of columns)

Having said that.. here is a reference to using the NSOperation class to lazy load your images into a UITableView while giving the user a smooth experience..

[UIImage in uitableViewcell slowdowns scrolling table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841791/uiimage-in-uitableviewcell-slowdowns-scrolling-table/5842137#5842137)